# Format \ref as a roman numeral? Strange bug

Tags: macros, cross-referencing, roman-numerals

How do I get a `\ref` to format as a Roman numeral?

At the moment I have the code:

```
\newcommand{\appendixref}[1]{Appendix~\romannumeral 0\ref{#1}\relax}
```

This works great... except for when it doesn't. Take a look at the image bellow:

[image: Example of it both working and not working in the same paragraph]

Which in the LaTeX the code is:

```
A single state of the board is represented with a \inlinecode{BoardState} (see \textbf{\appendixref{BoardState}}) interface. A state contains all the relevant information about the current state of a board that makes it unique from another state of the board.. For the purpose of my application, I extended this to create an \inlinecode{AbstractBoardState} (see \textbf{\appendixref{AbstractBoardState}}) which contained a lot of the common code between the two types of \inlinecode{BoardState}
```

I would say it works about 85% of the time. I would like a solution that works all the time and a possible explanation for why this is not working all the time.

To provide some more context, I have an appendix defined as the following environment:

```
\renewenvironment{appendix}[1][section]{
    \newcommand{\oldsection}{#1}
    \newcounter{oldsection}
    \setcounter{oldsection}{\value{#1}}
    \setcounter{#1}{0}
    \expandafter\renewcommand\csname the#1\endcsname{\roman{#1}}
}{
    \setcounter{\oldsection}{\value{oldsection}}
}
```

An example usage of this environment is as follows:

```
\begin{appendix}[subsection]
\section{Appendix}

\subsection{Tile.java} \label{Tile}
\javascript{tile/Tile}{Tagging interface for tiles}

\end{appendix}
```

This would produce a section Appendix with a apendix that uses roman numerals. The Roman numerals appear perfectly besides the header and also in the TOC, it is just where I used the `\appendixref{Title}` macro that *sometimes* it does not work. Here is the screenshot showing how the TOC might be produced for a document including an appendix as described above.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you add an example of how you're using this new environment?

Comment: @egreg Thank you. I have made the amendments with the example usage. I have also added the code for the first image example.

Comment: One thing that is suspicious from your code is the `appendix` environment's starting definition that just sets a counter rather than using something like `\refstepcounter` (or setting `\@currentlabel` directly). That is used in terms of storing the label when you `\ref` it.

Comment: It would be *really* helpful if you could create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that is complete (we should be able to copy-and-paste, compile, and replicate your output).

Comment: I don't see anything strange; move the `\newcounter` declaration outside the `\renewenvironment` and also remove `\romannumeral 0` from the defition of `\appendixref`, because it serves no purpose: the reference will already be in lowercase Roman numerals.

Comment: Right, seems to be working when I make a blank document even as @egreg says without the "\romannumeral 0" but it does not in my working document, there must be a package that is interfering with the correct functionality.

Comment: @flungo There's nothing else to do than trying to produce a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Found the error while slowly taking bits out of my code till it worked. Basically I had the following macro:

    `\newcommand{\javascript}[2]{
    \begin{itemize}
    \item[]\lstinputlisting[caption=#2,label=#1]{#1.java}
    \end{itemize}
    }`

And each time I was adding an appendix, I was using:

    `\subsection{Tile.java} \label{Tile}
    \javascript{tile/Tile}{Tagging interface for tiles}`

For example, so Where the first argument of javascript was the same as the first argument of the label, I was doubly defining the label due to the `label=#1` in the macro.

Comment: error in local code (which the OP has fixed while trying to construct a MWE)